talking empathetically or by talking?
what is the difference between the two sentences. is it grammatically appropriate?
She comforted her friend, talking empathetically.
She comforted her friend by talking empathetically.
or
He entered the room, shouting.
He entered the room by shouting

You can't enter a room "by" shouting. Please look up the word "by" in a dictionary.


[1a] She comforted her friend, talking empathetically.


[1b] She comforted her friend by talking empathetically.


[2a] He entered the room, shouting.


[2b] He entered the room by shouting.

The first pair have almost similar meanings. [1b] means the comforting was achieved through the manner of talking.  [1a] doesn’t have such clear emphasis, but we know that while she was comforting her friend, she also talked empathetically.
In [2a], the shouting describes the manner of his entry to the room.
[2b] is different from [2a]. What works in [1b], that is, the by + verbing construction, doesn’t work here.  This example means his entry to the room is through shouting, which doesn't make sense.
